# Why is my popover crashing in iOS 8.1 on iPhone 6 Plus? iOS 8 worked (actually Xcode 6.0 to 6.1 bug)

Tags: ios, ios8, uipopovercontroller

I was happy to see that Apple was allowing popovers on iPhone in iOS 8 (in certain cases anyway, larger iPhones, landscape only) and I switched some code from showing UIPickerview to UIPopoverController, like I use in this app for iPad. Now I'm getting reports of this crashing in iOS 8.1, and in my tests I see the crash on the second line below:

```
    XfrGraphTypeVC *graphTypePopover = [[XfrGraphTypeVC alloc]
                                    initWithNibName:@"XfrGraphTypeVC"
                                    bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                    type:xfrChannelMode cellHeight:cellHt];

self.popoverController = [[NSClassFromString(@"UIPopoverController") alloc] initWithContentViewController:graphTypePopover];
```

I've tried a few things to work around it, but no luck. Works fine still on iPad. Did Apple break something?

Edit: Still not working. Apple changed something in 8.1 to break this. What could be going on?

Edit: Now I think this started with Xcode 6.1, as apps built with Xcode 6.0 don't crash.

Crash Log:

```
    Incident Identifier: CD6192B8-363D-4EAB-9392-8A366D1FD10C
CrashReporter Key:   797d45c1f30283e0885ce0a30c88ccdf6fd78036
Hardware Model:      iPhone7,1
Process:             AudioTools [4530]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/5EDE9ACF-5372-45B8-B370-3AFFD345ED24/AudioTools.app/AudioTools
Identifier:          com.studiosixdigital.audiotools
Version:             7.3.11 (7.3.11)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2014-11-11 17:10:31.927 -0800
Launch Time:         2014-11-11 17:10:26.147 -0800
OS Version:          iOS 8.1 (12B411)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x2379fc1f _exceptionPreprocess + 127
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x30fafc8b objc_exception_throw + 38
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2379fb65 +[NSException raise:format:] + 112
3   UIKit                           0x26e8a41b -[UIPopoverController _initWithContentViewController:popoverControllerStyle:] + 266
4   AudioTools                      0x004f4065 0x69000 + 4763749
5   UIKit                           0x26c8fc2b -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 70
6   UIKit                           0x26c8fbd1 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 44
7   UIKit                           0x26c7a863 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 582
8   UIKit                           0x26c8f63d -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 588
9   UIKit                           0x26c8f317 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 522
10  UIKit                           0x26c88be1 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 544
11  UIKit                           0x26c5f3dd -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 196
12  UIKit                           0x26ed2c29 _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 13888
13  UIKit                           0x26c5de39 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 1296
14  CoreFoundation                  0x23766377 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
15  CoreFoundation                  0x23765787 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 218
16  CoreFoundation                  0x23763ded __CFRunLoopRun + 772
17  CoreFoundation                  0x236b2211 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 476
18  CoreFoundation                  0x236b2023 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
19  GraphicsServices                0x2aa650a9 GSEventRunModal + 136
20  UIKit                           0x26cbe1d1 UIApplicationMain + 1440
21  AudioTools                      0x0007c647 main + 50
22  AudioTools                      0x0006d028 start + 40
```

Comment: Can you share the exception that's causing the crash? Should be shown in the console.

Comment: Just added. Wow who down voted this, Apple?

Comment: Why this `[NSClassFromString(@"UIPopoverController") alloc]` instead of `[UIPopoverController alloc]`? And can you symbolicate the crash log?

Comment: That's just to prevent crashes on older iOS that do not support popovers. I'll try to symbolicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so I downloaded Xcode 6.0.1 and now this all works again. So it's something Apple broke in Xcode 6.1. I thought it was in iOS 8.1 because that happened at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

`UIPopoverController` is still only for iPads.

From [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverController_class/index.html):

> Popover controllers are for use exclusively on iPad devices.
>   Attempting to create one on other devices results in an exception.

So it won't work on iPhone devices. Probably they broke something on the previous version, that's why it worked for you.